# Why am I getting an IntegrityError when attempting to import JSON?

Tags: python, django, json, export

I am trying to export some data from a MySQL database and import it into a PostgreSQL database. The two models are described below:

```
class Location(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Item(models.Model):
    title    = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    location = models.ForeignKey(Location)

class Book(Item):
    author = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

Notice that the `Book` model inherits from the `Item` model. (Also, I do realize that `author` really should be a separate model - but I need something simple to demonstrate the problem.) I first attempt to export the data from the model using the `dumpdata` command:

```
./manage.py dumpdata myapp.location >locations.json
./manage.py dumpdata myapp.item >items.json
./manage.py dumpdata myapp.book >books.json
```

The JSON in `items.json` looks something like this:

```
{
    "fields": {
        "title": "Introduction to Programming",
        "location": 1
    },
    "model": "myapp.item",
    "pk": 1
}
```

The JSON in `books.json` looks something like this:

```
{
    "fields": {
        "author": "Smith, Bob"
    },
    "model": "myapp.book",
    "pk": 1
}
```

I can import `locations.json` and `items.json` without issue but as soon as I attempt to import `books.json`, I run into the following error:

```
IntegrityError: Problem installing fixture 'books.json': Could not load
  myapp.Book(pk=1): null value in column "location_id" violates not-null
  constraint
```

---

**Edit:** the schema for `myapp.books` (according to PostgreSQL itself) is as follows:

```
# SELECT * FROM myapp_book;
 item_ptr_id | author
-------------+--------
(0 rows)
```

Comment: I'm not sure why this was downvoted?

Answer (score 1):

The books.json file needs to have all the fields of the parent model, in your case 'title' and 'location' fields (and appropriate values of course) need to be added (from the items.json file). loaddata doesn't use the database structure (with intermediate the table and all), but the checks the actual fields of the model.

To avoid ending up with double entries, you will also have to remove all the json entries in the items.json file that are pointed to by the original mysql database in the myapp_book table.

Another solution would be to use http://pypi.python.org/pypi/py-mysql2pgsql (see also [this question)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8895374/changing-django-database-backend-from-mysql-to-postgresql)

Answer (score 0):

Seems like for whatever reason the Books schema in your postgres db doesn't match the models - it has a location_id column. You should drop the table and rerun syncdb.

Comment: I've updated my question with the current schema according to PostgreSQL. In addition, the field that Django is complaining about isn't *in* the `Book` model - it's in the `Item` model.